# Number of ways to seat $n_i$ people around a round table with $n$ seats $\bigl(n_i \lt n \bigl)$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

So the question says to find the number of ways to seat $n_i$ people around a roundtable with $n$ seats $\bigl(n_i \lt n \bigl)$.
The first thing I did was select $n_i$ seats from $n \Rightarrow \binom {n}{n_i}$
Now the number of ways to arrange these $n_i$ people is obviously $\bigl(n_i -1 \bigl)!$
So we get, $$\binom {n}{n_i} \cdot \Bigl(n_i -1\Bigl)!$$ 
The answer however given is $$\left( \frac{n!}{\Bigl(n-n_i\Bigl)!}\right)$$
Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why are you choosing $n_i$ people, don't we have only $n_i$ people?

Comment: Sorry I meant $n_i$ seats.

Comment: To make sure, so if $n_i=1$ and $n=4$, there are four ways to seat one person around the table?

Comment: I'm not sure would it be 3 or 4?

Comment: I think it should be 1.

Comment: would there not be $n_i!$ ways to rearrange $n_i$ people?

Comment: Well, the answer shows that they are counting rotations distinguishable... So that one person can take any four of the seats and they are distinguishable. Therefore, it is $4$ ways. It never said rotations are indistinguishable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is finding all permutations and dividing by the number of spaces since they are indistinguishable. However, you should note that there are $n_i!$ ways to arrange them since they can have any permutation. (Rotations are distinguishable in this case, since there is nothing to account for overcount in the answer.)

When we implement this, we get $\dfrac{n!}{n_i!(n-n_i)!}\cdot n_i!=\dfrac{n!}{(n-n_i)!},$ which is the answer given.

Comment: I understand. Thank you